# In R, how do I list the values of a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = data.frame('A' = c(10:20))
df.ts = ts(c(10:20) * 10)
```

Then, I can get some info about `df`

```
summary(df)
       A       
 Min.   :10.0  
 1st Qu.:12.5  
 Median :15.0  
 Mean   :15.0  
 3rd Qu.:17.5  
 Max.   :20.0
```

But `summary` doesn't mention that `ts` exists. How do I get a list of the values associated to a dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

Because `df.ts` is a different object identifier.  The `.` doesn't evaluate to extracting/creating object properties/columns in `R`. We create a column in the same object with `$` or `[[`

```
df$ts <-  ts(c(10:20) * 10)
```

Now, if we apply `summary`

```
summary(df)
#       A              ts     
# Min.   :10.0   Min.   :100  
# 1st Qu.:12.5   1st Qu.:125  
# Median :15.0   Median :150  
# Mean   :15.0   Mean   :150  
# 3rd Qu.:17.5   3rd Qu.:175  
# Max.   :20.0   Max.   :200
```